# Couchdb/Cloudant view for document property with array

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I have three docs in CouchDB/Cloudant as follows:

```
all_docs :[{
    _id: "content1"
    files: ["fileA", "fileB", "fileC"]
}, {
    _id: "content2"
    files: ["fileD", "fileE", "fileC"]
}, {
    _id: "content3"
    files: ["fileF", "fileG", "fileH"]
}
```

I need to get content1 and content2 as result for FileC where I can pass FileC as key.

Is there a way to write a view that returns doc ids (content1 and content2) where the file is FileC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This just requires a standard, straight-forward view.

As [documented](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/ddocs/ddocs.html#view-functions):

> Note that `emit()` may be called many times for a single document, so the same document may be available by several different keys.

So you just need to call `emit()` for each file in the document.  Something like this:

```
function (doc) {
  for (i = 0; i < doc.files.length; i++) {
    emit(doc.files[0])
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Flimzy!